# JavaScript - changing HTML via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a webpage and I'm trying to edit the HTML via JS via the URL bar.

I'm not too well educated in JS but I thought I'd have known enough to complete this:
I'm also not sure why this isn't working.
I've got this code:

javascript:

```
function textIncrement(eID){
    for (i=0;i>1000;i++){
        document.getElementById.('eID'.innerHTML='i')
    }
}
textIncrement();
```

The picture below shows the HTML formatting:

[image: HTML formatting]

I want to change the highlighted text ("6,097") - from what I know, the element ID for the text is ("points-zFkA6").
The current code should replace the number by the value "i", however the element doesn't change.

So can someone help me to identify where the problem is?

### --

EDIT:

I had some errors in my code, fixed for future references:

```
// I don't need to define the variables, this is just for future reference.
//
alert(pointsToAdd);
alert(image);
if(pointsToAdd != null){
    if(image != null){
        for (var i=0;i<pointsToAdd;i++){
            setTimeout(function() {
                var elementsIn = document.getElementsByClassName(image);
                elementsIn[0].innerHTML = toAdd;
                toAdd = toAdd + 1;
            },500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop is incorrect<sup>†</sup>. The condition:

```
for (i = 0; i > 1000; i++)
//          ^^^^^^^^
```

is always false but the loop will only run if the condition is true. You need to change it to `i < 1000`. Moreover, this:

```
document.getElementById.('eID'.innerHTML='i')
```

needs to be

```
document.getElementById(eID).innerHTML = i;
```

You messed up the syntax and you used strings where you should be using the variable names. And when you call the function, you need to call the function with the id name.

```
textIncrement("idName");
```

<sub><sup>†</sup>Always use `var` when creating variable names. Otherwise it creates a global variable which isn't good.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the html attribute wrong, you are giving it a class= but really you want to use id=
And on further inspection, the id you are looking for doesn't seem to be set anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's a typo, but the fourth line should look like this:

```
document.getElementById(eID).innerHtml = i;
```

You've got the parens in the wrong place, and you don't want to put quotes around the argument. Also, as the other answer said, you might have `class` and `id` mixed up.